# Where are Google Earth files on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-earth

The following information is irrelevant: https://support.google.com/earth/answer/166438?hl=en

I.e. I don't have  "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Google\GoogleEarth" location.

Comment: The very next line in the tutorial says `•If you're using Windows 7 or Windows Vista, enter "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local". If that path doesn't work, enter "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth".`...?

Comment: The very next line refers to incorrect OS.

Comment: Yes, but did you check them?

Answer (score 4):

Please keep in mind that on a Windows 10 machine, `Documents and Settings` is a [Junction Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968829(VS.85).aspx) for the `Users` folder.

That being said, the same Google tutorial also says to check the following locations:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
>
> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth

Comment: So, there are 2 mistakes in Google doc: (1) `Documents and Settings` mentionned instead of `Users` and (2) `Application Data` is mentionned instead of `AppData`, right?

Comment: No, not really.  That tutorial implies that the `Documents and Settings` path is appropriate for legacy versions of Windows prior to Vista.  In subsequent versions of the operating system, the newer `Users` paths are correct.